# Why Start field on Event minipagelayout can not be removed?

Tags: page-layout, event, mini-page-layout

> Error: Cannot remove field: Start

Unable to remove Start (DateTime) field from the event mini page layout.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> Fields marked Always Displayed or Always on Layout on page layouts are
>   automatically included on the mini page layout and cannot be removed
>   unless they are removed from the page layout.

[image]
This is why because the field is required. As `Start` is a standard field we cannot customize its properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I have to remove the Start field anyhow as I do not want to display the 'Check availability' link on UI. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: @Rohit you cannot remove `Start` field. See this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqEzAAK

Comment: Can you brief what is 'Check availability' link here

Comment: 'Check Availability' link gets automatically displayed on Event detail page and in mini pagelayout along with Start Date.